# Simple SFTP transfer log

Tags: ssh, logging, sftp

I am looking for a way to log transfers over SFTP in Ubuntu. Nothing complicated, just a log where I can see which users have down/uploaded certain files. I [read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way) but setting the `-l INFO` flag in sshd_config appears to not be working. Should that work for my purpose, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered: [SFTP logging: is there a way?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way)

For those of us on earlier versions of sshd (centos5 and the like) check out this patch: http://sftplogging.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I included the same link in my post, and indicated that the -l INFO flag did not affect my log files at all. On Ubuntu where should those transfers be logged?

Comment: What version sshd do you have? as it says, this only works at 4.4 or greater.  (`sshd -V` shows version) The log messages could be getting filtered by syslog because they are too low/verbose a level. I don't know what the default syslog.conf is on ubuntu, but try this:  check for the file where where the normal sshd messages go. (`/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` maybe) Look at /etc/syslog.conf for the line with that logfile name in it, and make sure the loglevel specification on the left says '_facility_.*'.