# Modifying httpd.conf to adjust for mod_wsgi and django install then cannot connect via sftp

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, sftp, mod-wsgi

I modified my httpd.conf file to point to a .wsgi file that I made directing apache to different document root. The server works fine, I see my application live on the net and I am still connected via SSH. However, I was kicked off my sftp and I cannot get back into it. I am using a .pem key as well. Has this happened to anyone? Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

I am using an Amazon Linux AMI with an EC2 Instance running apache2, python 2.6, mysql, mod_wsgi

**EDIT:** I just refreshed my webpage once again (10 minutes after being kicked off the ftp) and I get a page could not be found by my browser, as if the server is not active. EC2 shows the instance is still running, even after refreshing it.

Comment: Turn on [logging](http://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way) to see what does it say.