# How do I see the changes an FTP user made in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

We are using CentOS 6 and internal-sftp and we gave access to an outside user, but I'm not seeing how to find out what changes they've made through FTP.

Comment: Did you try looking in the ftp logs?

Comment: @user2344668 do you mean FTP or SFTP? These are completely different things, SFTP is part of the SSH protocol.

Answer (score 0):

if it's SFTP you probably need to look at logging for it like they talk about here [SFTP logging: is there a way?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way)