# Ansible: Raise Error if replace did not find anything to replace

Tags: ansible

How do you solve this in Ansible?

I have a file `/etc/foo/foo.config`. I want to replace the string "DisallowBar" to "AlllowBarUntilMidnight" in this file.

Ansible should act in these cases like this:

- Case1: DisallowBar gets found and gets replaced: OK
- Case2: AllowBarUntilMidnight is already in the file. Nothing gets done: OK
- Case3: DisallowBar and AllowBarUntilMidnight are not in the file: I want ansible to fail.

Case3 is important for me, since this state should not exist. It is an error and this should not pass silently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `validate` parameter of [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) to ensure that the file that would be written contains `AllowBarUntilMidnight` and no longer contains `DisallowBar`.

```
tasks:
- name: replace DisallowBar 
  replace:
    path: /etc/foo/foo.config
    regexp: 'DisallowBar'
    replace: "AllowBarUntilMidnight"
    validate: 'grep "AllowBarUntilMidnight" %s'
```

The `validate` command runs on the generated temporary file before it is copied into place after the `replace` runs. In this case, if the `grep` fails, it means no replacement took place, and your original file never contained `DisallowBar` to begin with. The play then fails and the file is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rely on the default behavior of the [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) function to ensure that the file won't contain the string `DisallowBar` anymore.

After that replace task has run you only need to confirm that the file does contain the string `AllowBarUntilMidnight` and raise an error if it doesn't.  You can do that with a simple `grep`.

```
  tasks:
  - name: replace DisallowBar 
    replace:
      path: /etc/foo/foo.config
      regexp: 'DisallowBar'
      replace: "AllowBarUntilMidnight"

  - name: Check for AllowBarUntilMidnight setting
    shell: grep "AllowBarUntilMidnight"  /etc/foo/foo.config
```